# Data validation on curdate() group by error code 1111

Tags: mysql

This is relatively easy but I've been staring at the code too long and making mistakes. I need to validate that a table has been populated for the day and the query simply takes today's date - curdate() - against the date_pulled column but I'm getting Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function. Where am I messing up.

```
 select * from test where max(date(date_pulled))=curdate();
```

Comment: `max()` doesn't make sense in this context. Try without.

Comment: @echo_Me         Thanks! Worked spot-on. I made something simple too complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need max here. you already telling the query to choose the date which is equal to current date.

try that:

```
  select * from test where date(date_pulled)=curdate();
```